# POSTing using ReactJS, Superagent and Python (flask)

Tags: javascript, python, flask, reactjs, superagent

I'm trying to post some data to a Python backend that i made with Flask. I'm using [SuperAgent](https://github.com/visionmedia/superagent) in a React component. For some reason i keep getting HTTP error 400.

I've read many posts about similar problems using JQuery and flask. The solution there is to set the contentType the same way i have and also JSON.stringify the data. I've tried stringify but it doesn't change anything. Still getting an HTTP 400.

Any ideas?

JS code:

```
request.post(link)
 .set('Content-Type', 'application/json; charset=utf-8')
 .send({tag: 'tag1', comment: 'Cool'})
 .end(function(err, res){
    console.log(res);
 });
```

Python function/endpoint:

```
@app.route('/api/leavecomments', methods=['POST'])
def comment_to_photos():
  comment = request.form['comment']
  print(comment)
  tag = request.form['tag']
...
```

Comment: superagent version: 1.6.1
flask version: 0.10.1

Comment: please see this documentation http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/0.10/api/#flask.Request.get_json

Comment: Wow thanks! I did focus entirely in the JavaScript part but it turns out the problem was in the Python side of things. Using get_json did solve my problem! If you post that answer underneath I'll mark it as the one that solved my problem. Thanks a lot!

Comment: okay thank you, I did :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So the issue for anybody else that has this problem, they need to use method named **get_json** which will have the values being passed to it in JSON format.  In the case of the code above it was looking for those values as a query string post parameters, which is typically sent via form posts.  In the case of an AJAX JSON post, the data exists inside the request.body.

For more information check out...

http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/0.10/api/#flask.Request.get_json